# Prediction Error on training and evaluating prediction models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression, svm

I am trying to train and evaluate prediction models using a dataset I found on Kaggle, but my precision is 0 and I am wondering if I am doing something wrong

The code works for the random forest model, but not SVM or neural networks

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
%matplotlib inline

#loading dataset
recipes = pd.read_csv('epi_r.csv')

keep_col = ['rating','calories','protein','fat','sodium']
recipes = recipes[keep_col]
recipes = recipes.dropna()

#preprocessing data
bins = (-1, 4, 5)
group_names = ['bad','good']
recipes['rating'] = pd.cut(recipes['rating'].dropna(), bins = bins,           labels = group_names)
recipes['rating'].unique()

#bad=0; good=1
label_rating = LabelEncoder()

recipes['rating'] =        label_rating.fit_transform(recipes['rating'].astype(str))

#separate dataset as response variable and feature variables
x = recipes.drop('rating', axis=1)
y = recipes['rating']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size   = 0.20, random_state = 42)

#converts the values & levels the playing fields
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
#don't fit again b/c want to use the same fit
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

clf=svm.SVC()
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred_clf = clf.predict(x_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, pred_clf))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_clf))



precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.00      0.00      0.00      1465
       1       0.54      1.00      0.70      1708

   micro avg       0.54      0.54      0.54      3173
   macro avg       0.27      0.50      0.35      3173
weighted avg       0.29      0.54      0.38      3173

[[   0 1465]
 [   0 1708]]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1143: UndefinedMetricWarning:    Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

this is the result I get, nothing is being predicted right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have not found the right parameters. For example, in your case you are overfitting. You should try GridSearchCV to find best parameters (especially kernel, C and gamma) for your dataset.

I played a little bit with your dataset and tried the following change,

```
clf=SVC(kernel='sigmoid', C=10, verbose=True)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred_clf = clf.predict(x_test)
print(pred_clf)
print(classification_report(y_test, pred_clf))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_clf))
```

Output:

```
......
Warning: using -h 0 may be faster
*
optimization finished, #iter = 6651
obj = -196704.694272, rho = 33.691873
nSV = 9068, nBSV = 9068
Total nSV = 9068
[LibSVM][0 1 1 ... 0 1 0]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.49      0.58      0.53      1465
           1       0.58      0.49      0.53      1708

    accuracy                           0.53      3173
   macro avg       0.53      0.53      0.53      3173
weighted avg       0.54      0.53      0.53      3173

[[843 622]
 [864 844]]
```

The result is not that great, but it is not all ones.

To summarize, do the following:

1. Always try cross-validation to find a good set of parameters for your dataset
2. Turn on verbose option of your estimator. This gives you important clues about what is going on
3. Always try to visualize and use simpler algorithms first, e.g. I would probably try to get an idea of whether the data is linearly separable, try logistic regression, and only then try something like SVM or ensembles. These are always harder to tune

Answer (score 2):

Class 1 has a recall of 1.0, meaning that your model is always predicting "1".
You can also see this from the confusion matrix, where 1708 values are predicted correctly for class 1, but 1465 values for class 0 are predicted as class 1.

A model always predicting a single value is a common problem -- it has got trapped in some kind of sub-optimal solution. You might find luck with normalising the input values (so one column doesn't dominate), using a different type of model (eg a different kernel) or even selecting a different random seed.